# MySQL Connections staying open (I think...)

Tags: mysql

Alright, so this morning I got a giant spam of automated mails from my vbulletin website with mysql errors stating

> `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'"
>
> Too many connections
>
> User username already has more than 'max_user_connections' active
>   connections`.

I've never had this before on my host, I don't get that many visitors on my two sites. One site running vbulletin gets between 300-700 daily visits and my second site is one I put together myself so that's probably the source of the connections staying open, I started advertising it yesterday but it doesn't get many visitors either so i don't think it's just too many users connecting, I think it's connections staying open or something...

Is there some way to figure out the source of this, or the location where connections stay open too long or any information would be helpful actually.

Thanks

Comment: how do you/vbulletin connect to the mysql? pdo? mysqli, old mysql_connect()?

Comment: Frankly about vBulletin I've got no clue, but I never had this before with my vBulletin site, my new site uses mysqli though

Answer (score 0):

In a MySQL shell you could run `show processlist;` which will show you currently running processes, what user is logged in, what database they have selected and what host they're coming from. This might give you some clues to the origin of your excess connections. Maybe you can see queries that are running for a very long time (combine that with an impatient user repeatedly hitting refresh).

Keep in mind that if any of your code runs with persistent connections there will be a bunch of idle processes in that list, which is perfectly normal in that case.